# JavaScript checking for whitespace and invalid characters

Tags: javascript, validation, diacritics, alphabetic

I am trying to check whether or not a certain string contains only A-Z, hyphen, apostrophes and accents (e.g. umlauts, etc).

I have the following but it is not working.

```
var lastNameValidation = /^[a-zA-ZàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ]$/;

var customerFullName = (inputData.customerName).replace(/\s/g, "");

if (!(customerFullName.matches(lastNameValidation))) {
    inputValidation += 'Invalid characters in first or last name. Only alphabetic letters, apostrophe, accents and hypen characters allowed<br/>';
}
```

I have removed whitespace from customerFullName and it appears to work correctly (I used an alert box to check)

I have tried both .matches and .test, but neither seem to work for me!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add + $ at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex to

```
 var lastNameValidation = /^[a-zA-ZàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ]+$/i
```

and use .match() . .matches() is not for string regex matching.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

```js
var check = function() {

  var lastNameValidation = /^[a-zA-ZàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ]+$/i
  
  var custname = document.querySelector("#name").value;

  var customerFullName = custname.replace(/\s/g, "");

  if (!(customerFullName.match(lastNameValidation))) {
    alert('Invalid characters in first or last name. Only alphabetic letters, apostrophe, accents and hypen characters allowed<br/>');
  } else {
    alert("perfect")
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="name">
<input type="button" value="check" onclick="check()">
```

Comment: It's much simpler to use `.test` that returns a boolean if a match was found, than `.replace`.

Comment: .replace is used to remove the spaces between name string by OP only,  i.e john doe will change to johndoe